# Javascript if/else statement in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So I'm trying to use javascript to pop up a video, and need to know when I'm in an iframe so I can resize the video accordingly.

When outside the iframe, I see three alerts ('this is seen by both', 'not in iframe', and 'this is after the fact')

When in the iframe, I just see the first alert ('this is seen by both').

```
var handleViewVideoClick = function (dataAction, eventType, targetElement, dataActionElement) {
alert('this is seen by both');
if ($('iframe', window.parent.document).length == 0) {
            alert('not in iframe');
} else {
            alert('in iframe');
}
alert('this is after the fact...');
};
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be you're not loading jQuery in that window, resulting in a `$ is undefined` error.  But no worries, you don't *need* jQuery anyway, just check if the current frame is also the top frame, like this:

```
if (self != top) {
  alert("I'm in an iframe, :(");
} else {
  alert("I'm freeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee!");
}
```